# Django - how to delete an object using a view

Tags: html, django, templates, view

I have the class People

```
class People (models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank = True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length = 2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I have the delete view

```
def delete(request):
    query = People.objects.get(pk=id)
    query.delete()
    return HttpResponse("Deleted!")
```

And I have the html template code

```
{% for person in people_list %}
<TR ALIGN="CENTER">
        <td>{{ person.first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.grade }}</td>
    <td><form action="/modify.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Modify">
        </form></td>
    <td><form action="/delete.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        </form></td>
</TR>
      {% endfor %}
```

How can I get the person.id from the template and put it in the delete view and delete the object corresponding with the person.id I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have your `delete` function(btw, name it something else, like `delete_person`) take in an argument, pk.

```
def delete_person(request, pk):
    ...
    ...
```

Then in your urlconf, do something like this

```
url(r'^delete_person/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'delete_person', name='delete_person')
```

And then generate the url in the template like so

```
{% url 'delete-person' person.id %}
```

PS - No need to have your urls end with `.html`

PPS - Would be a good idea to do some validation in the view to make sure that the user is authorized to delete the person.

Comment: You're my man! Our answers are has differences but the way is nearly identical. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use a link instead of form:

Replace this line

```
<td>
  <form action="/delete.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>
</td>
```

with this

```
<td><a href="/delete/{{ person.id }}">Delete</a></td>
```

In urls.py you should add the following line to relate your view with url:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<person_pk>.*)$', 'person.views.delete' name='delete-person'),
```

Then change your view:

```
def delete(request, person_pk):
    query = People.objects.get(pk=person_pk)
    query.delete()
    return HttpResponse("Deleted!")
```

Comment: That's a very bad idea. Actions that modify the database shouldn't be called with GET.

Comment: I want to do just a simple project app

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't think so, if you make required controls within your view, it doesn't matter if it is get, post, delete or whatever. Since I can simulate all types of requests, all http requests are vulnerable at same level.

Comment: @DanielRoseman unless the `csrf_middleware` is being used, wouldn't it be the same whether you use `POST` or `GET`? Though yes I agree that either a `POST` or an ajax `PUT` or `DELETE` request should be used to modify database objects.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @scriptmonster, I wrapped the query in a try except to properly return a 404

```
# urls.py
path("foo/<int:pk>/", views.ModelView.as_view(), name="foo-detail"),$
```

and

```
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound                                               

class ModelView(View):                                                                                             
    model = Foo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):                                                                       
        foo_id = kwargs["pk"]                                                                                      
        try:                                                                                                          
            query = Foo.objects.get(pk=foo_id)                                                                  
            query.delete()                                                                                            
            return HttpResponse("Deleted!")                                                                           
        except:                                                                                                       
            return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from test_app.(your Application Name) import views

path('delete/(?p<id>\d+)/',views.delete_View(),
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.

Answer (score 0):

to delete an object by class based view:

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
class PeopleDeleteView(generic.edit.DeleteView):
    model = People
    success_url = reverse_lazy('people_list')
```

urls.py

```
...
path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.PeopleDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
```

you need a delete confirmation template:

myapp/people_confirmation_delete.html

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```